# Reading text file as array

Tags: php, arrays

I want to transform a text file into an array, here is what the text file looks like

```
code 1 #Updated 12/15/2000
{
Reezena of Confinement
}
code 2 #Added in v2.0
{
Neil
}
code 3 #Added in V1.0
{
Jansen
}
code 4 #Updated 12/15/2000
{
Gellos
}
```

and what it should like after its done

```
array(
'1' => "Reezena of Confinement",
'2' => "Neil",
'3' => "Jansen",
'4' => "Gellos",
)
```

Ive tryed this:

```
preg_match_all('/{(.*?)}/s', $html, $matches);

//HTML array in $matches[1]
echo "<pre>";
print_r($matches[1]);
echo "</pre>";
```

However its missing the "code XXX"
somehow i need to grab it

thx in advance

Comment: Were you hoping we'd write the code for you? If so, you're in the wrong place.

Comment: Show what you tried for this ?

Comment: Nope, edited question, just wanted to know if it was even possible or not

Comment: I wasn't expecting to get the code, but THX allot !!!!!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
    $str = file_get_contents ( 't.txt' );

    preg_match_all ( '@code\s+(\d+)[^{]*{([^}]+)}@', $str, $matches );

    $result = array ();

    foreach ( $matches [1] as $k => $id )
    {
        $result [$id] = trim ( $matches [2] [$k] );
    }

    var_dump ( $result );
```

Comment: Worked perfectly, Thx allot !

Answer (score 0):

Make use of the [`file()`](https://www.php.net/function.file) on PHP

```
<?php
$arr=file('new.txt'); //Save all the content what you pasted in a file named new.txt
for($i=2;$i<count($arr);$i=$i+4)
{
    echo $arr[$i];
    echo "<br>";
}
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
Reezena of Confinement 
Neil 
Jansen 
Gellos
```

Comment: I think OP wants `code` prefix to determine result array's keys

Comment: Yep ;) i needed to code

Answer (score 0):

My solution without any `preg`-like functions;

```
$txt = "code 1 #Updated 12/15/2000
{
Reezena of Confinement
}
code 2 #Added in v2.0
{
Neil
}
code 3 #Added in V1.0
{
Jansen
}
code 4 #Updated 12/15/2000
{
Gellos
}";


$lines = explode("\n", $txt);

$array = array();
$key = NULL;

foreach($lines as $line) {
    if(trim($line) === '{' || trim($line) === '}') {
        continue;
    }
    if(substr($line, 0, 4) == 'code') {
        $exploded = explode(' ', $line);
        $key = $exploded[1];
        continue;
    }
    if(isset($key)) {
        $array[$key] = $line;
        $key = NULL;
    }
}
echo "<pre>";
print_r($array);
echo "</pre>";
```

Results;

```
Array
(
    [1] => Reezena of Confinement
    [2] => Neil
    [3] => Jansen
    [4] => Gellos
)
```